# With a compass and straightedge, is it possible to construct the square of a given distance?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given two line segments A and B of arbitrary length, is it possible to construct a segment C such that the proportion of C to A is equal to the proportion of [the area of a square with side B] to [the area of a square with side A]?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $DEF$ is a right triangle, $D=90^\circ$ and $DH$ is the altitude, then 
$$DH^2=EH \cdot FH$$
Now construct a right triangle such that $EH=1$ and $DH$ is the given distance.

Comment: Is $A$ a point, a segment or an angle?

Comment: $A$ is a vertex of the triangle $ABC$.

Comment: Right. I raised the question since you've given it an angle but OPs defined it as a segment. Could possibly be confusing for them.

Comment: @Jam Rewrote it.